# Updating a column shows syntax error in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE datanyc_new t2
SET    Prevclose = t1.Last
FROM   datanyc t1
WHERE  t2.Symbol = t1.Symbol
AND    t2.`Timestamp` = '2020-01-03'
AND    t1.`Timestamp` = ( SELECT max( Timestamp ) FROM datanyc WHERE Timestamp= '2020-01-03')
```

This is the query I used.

[image]

Comment: Add error messages as text not as image

Comment: unsure, so I won't post it as an answer, but I'm pretty sure you need the `as` keyword when using aliases, so it should probably be something like: `FROM datanyc as t1` and `UPDATE datanyc_new as t2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple-table syntax: for mysql is

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Assuming the question is tagged correctly try

```
UPDATE datanyc_new dn join datanyc d on dn.Symbol = d.Symbol
SET    Prevclose = d.Last
WHERE  dn.`Timestamp` = '2020-01-03'
  AND  d.`Timestamp` = ( SELECT max(Timestamp) FROM datanyc WHERE Timestamp= '2020-01-03');
```

I'm not seeing the point of the subquery or possibly it is incorrect, if timestamp column contains datetime and the intention is to get the last time for 2020-01-03 then the where is incorrect and will return null you may need `WHERE date(timestamp) =  '2020-01-03'`

Comment: Did you try it with the suggested correction? Please add table definitions an sample data as text to the question.

Comment: yeah I changed the correction and now its working fine. Thank you!